# React this.props is undefined in state event?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events, react-props, apexcharts

I am trying to use `props` value in `dataPointSelection` in `apexchart` under state but I am getting error that `this.props` is undefined and also value not showing on console log. Here is my code that I did:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const { t, too, fromm } = this.props;
    console.log("Upper" + this.props.fromm);
    this.state = {
      ...props,
      options: {
        chart: {
          id: "Speeding",
          events: {
            dataPointSelection: function(event, chartContext, opts) {
              switch (opts.w.config.xaxis.categories[opts.dataPointIndex]) {
                case "0-10":
                  window.open(
                    window.location.origin +
                      `/overspeeding/10/0/${
                        this.props.too ? `${this.props.too}` : `${cc}`
                      }/${
                        this.props.fromm ? `${this.props.fromm}` : "2016-01-04"
                      }` // in this line i am getting error
                  );
```

How to resolve this error and user props value in event?

Comment: `props` a local variable (`constructor(props)`). No need for `this.`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that inside of the `function`, you don't have access to the same `this` than in the constructor. Instead you have access to the passed `props` object, that contains the props.

You should be fine by just replacing `this.props` with `props` there:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const { t, too, fromm } = props;
    console.log("Upper" + props.fromm);
    this.state = {
      ...props,
      options: {
        chart: {
          id: "Speeding",
          events: {
            dataPointSelection: function(event, chartContext, opts) {
              switch (opts.w.config.xaxis.categories[opts.dataPointIndex]) {
                case "0-10":
                  window.open(
                    window.location.origin +
                      `/overspeeding/10/0/${
                        props.too ? `${props.too}` : `${cc}`
                      }/${
                        props.fromm ? `${props.fromm}` : "2016-01-04"
                      }` // in this line i am getting error
                  );
```

Another way would be to bind the upper `this` to the new function using `.bind(this)`, or just using an arrow function that doesn't have its own `this:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const { t, too, fromm } = this.props;
    console.log("Upper" + this.props.fromm);
    this.state = {
      ...props,
      options: {
        chart: {
          id: "Speeding",
          events: {
            dataPointSelection: (event, chartContext, opts) => { // Arrow funciton
              switch (opts.w.config.xaxis.categories[opts.dataPointIndex]) {
                case "0-10":
                  window.open(
                    window.location.origin +
                      `/overspeeding/10/0/${
                        this.props.too ? `${this.props.too}` : `${cc}`
                      }/${
                        this.props.fromm ? `${this.props.fromm}` : "2016-01-04"
                      }` // in this line i am getting error
                  );
```

Using `function.bind`:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const { t, too, fromm } = this.props;
    console.log("Upper" + this.props.fromm);
    this.state = {
      ...props,
      options: {
        chart: {
          id: "Speeding",
          events: {
            dataPointSelection: function(event, chartContext, opts) {
              switch (opts.w.config.xaxis.categories[opts.dataPointIndex]) {
                case "0-10":
                  window.open(
                    window.location.origin +
                      `/overspeeding/10/0/${
                        this.props.too ? `${this.props.too}` : `${cc}`
                      }/${
                        this.props.fromm ? `${this.props.fromm}` : "2016-01-04"
                      }` // in this line i am getting error
                  );
                  // ...
                }
              }.bind(this)// Binding the upper this to function scope.
            // ...
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need this behind props in constructor normally. Try with just props